# What is the grommet called for a pipe clamp?

Tags: terminology

I bought a pipe clamp and after it arrived I found it does not tightly fit the pipe because I think it is supposed to be used with a grommet.

[image]

The problem is that to find a grommet to fit this thing, I need to know what it is called. What is the name of the item I need here?

(Note that it is NOT an electrical grommet. Electrical grommets that fit into a hole in sheet metal are totally different.)

Answer (score 1):

I would go to bicycle shop and get the rubber that goes around the handle bar for mounting lights and accessories or handle bar tape.

Or just use [rubberized electrical tape](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/electrical-construction-maintenance-us/resources/rubber-electrical-tape-guide/).

Just so this is an actual answer to the question

"What is the grommet called for a pipe clamp?"

That would be a Pipe clamp grommet or pipe clamp cushion.

Perhaps this [pipe strap dampener strip](https://www.radonaway.com/products/pipe-accessories/pipe-strap-dampener-strip.php) will work.

Oooohhh i got it. [Cush-a-strip](https://www.zsi-foster.com/products/cushioned-clamps/cush-a-strip/cush-a-strip-trade.html) !

Help i cant stop.   [Tico clamp strip](https://anti-vibration.solutions/s-cl-anti-vibration-pipe-strip.php).